# Send "GET" http request fails

Tags: java, android

I'm sorry to ask a stupid question, but I need help

I refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968114/android-sending-https-get-request), trying to use "GET" requests, and download page
But when I press the button, the application crashes

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void add(View view){ //button
        et2.setText(testget());
}

    public String testget(){
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI("http://61.218.228.98:8008/Verify.aspx?EleSignVerift=421E313B"));
    response = client.execute(request);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return response.toString();

}
```

---

I want to use the same way, a request to set up my site and download the results

I do not know where the wrong

Or I used the wrong way?

*edit*
---Error Messages

```
06-09 14:19:42.112    5470-5470/com.example.sw.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity



at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5079)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)



at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5079)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)


at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.example.sw.myapplication.MainActivity.testget(MainActivity.java:64)

at com.example.sw.myapplication.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5079)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at om.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

---AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GenerateQRCodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_generate_qrcode" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that the application crashes? Please post the LogCat output.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in your port `8008`?

Comment: Did you added internet permission? 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Yes, I have written "<uses-permission android: name =" android.permission.INTERNET "/>"

Comment: check this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174411/asynk-task-calling-in-loop-not-giving-the-value-return/19175748#19175748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.example.sw.myapplication.MainActivity.testget(MainActivity.java:64)
> at com.example.sw.myapplication.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:45)
> ```

Looks like you are getting null as response and `response.toString()` is throwing `NPE`. 
So you should firstly make http call asynchronously ( in AsyncTask).

See AsyncTask [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask). Another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939122/not-getting-response-response-httpclient-executerequest).

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be helpful, I will be more try

Answer (score 1):

Your `response` variable is null in case of any exceptions. 
Do you perform your internet connection on the background thread?
Also, `response.toString()` won't return you body of response. Read more about how to get body from http response.